# Compiling a specific version of a freeBSD utility

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I want to compile and run a specific version of a FreeBSD utility from the source code.

For example, I downloaded the repo for the following utility: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/sbin/routed/

However, when I run the `make` command, I get the following error:

```
"../Makefile.inc", line 3: Cannot open ../Makefile.inc
make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
*** [all] Error code 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the *whole* source tree. The build system depends on pieces from different locations in the tree. Then;

- Unpack the source in `/usr/src`
- `cd /usr/src/sbin/routed`
- `make && make install`

It looks like you want the 9-stable branch? If you have subversion available, you can do:

```
rm -rf /usr/src/
svn co svn://svn.freebsd.org/base/stable/9 /usr/src
```

(Depending on your FreeBSD version, `svn` may also be called `svnlite`) Also see the [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/svn.html).

On my machine, the complete `/usr/src` tree is 2445 MiB, including the `.svn` directory.

**Edit:** Note that it a program relies on system calls, library functions or other features that were introduced in a certain branch/version of FreeBSD, it will not work on older branches/versions.

Comment: Thanks I will try this right now. Just out of curiosity, isn't the whole source tree very large? You are saying that I should download the entire FreeBSD repo correct?

Comment: Not the *whole* SVN repo! Just the *branch* that you're interested in. See updated answer.

Comment: Just like to add that compiling a newer version of a utility on an older freebsd release will not always work.